# It is not waited by calling another asynchronous form

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#.
I want to launch another form asynchronously and continue processing after the HeavyMethod completes.
But Task.Result is executed without waiting for Task to finish.
How should i fix this code?

Append:
I set the current time on the attendance entry page with a Webbrowser control launched in anotherForm.
I launch the application in parallel with it.
The application startup process is also asynchronous, but not for low latency. I'm trying to keep the main form UI from getting stuck.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<bool> sampleTask = sampleAsync();

    if (startOutlookCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        rtn = await Task.Run(() => StartProcess(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE", ""));
        if (rtn)
        {
            // Wait for the app to start, don't start other apps at the same time
            await Task.Delay(10000); 
        }
    }

    if (startTeamsCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        rtn = await Task.Run(() => StartProcess(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData + @"\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe", "--processStart \"Teams.exe"));
        if (rtn)
        {
            // Wait for the app to start, don't start other apps at the same time
            await Task.Delay(5000); 
        }
    }

    try
    {
        // I want to wait for sample completion here
        bool taskResult = sampleTask.Reslt
        if (taskResult)
        {
            a();
        }
        else
        {
            b();
        }
    }
    // Exception handling
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(aex.InnerException.Message);  
        return;
    }
} 


public async Task<bool> sampleAsync()
{
    bool rtn = true;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Action act1 = (() =>
        {
            AnotherForm anotherForm = new AnotherForm();
            anotherForm.main = this;
            anotherForm.ShowDialog();
            // receive the return value from anotherForm
            rtn = manotherForm.rtn;
            anotherForm.Dispose();
        });
        this.BeginInvoke(act1);
    });
    return rtn;
}

private bool StartProcess(string exeFullPath, string param = "")
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(exeFullPath))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            {
                startApp = Process.Start(exeFullPath);
            }
            else
            {
                startApp = Process.Start(exeFullPath, param);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't create forms from a non-UI thread.

Comment: How does `Button_Click` relate to `StartMetsFormAsync`? You really should read [ask] and [mcve] and then fix your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity My application does two heavy things after the run button is pressed. The first process is executed in another form (web browser control). Running it serially would take too long, so I want to run it asynchronously and wait for both to complete before the application exits.

Comment: @Enigmativity  
sorry. I didn't understand your point correctly. I made some modifications to the question.The web browser control doesn't require user interaction, it's all handled by the application.

Comment: Thanks for the update. There are loads of syntax errors so this can't be your actual code. You really should post actual code.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I try to follow "create a Minimal, Reproducible Example". There were some syntax errors, but I hope this gives you some insight into my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would handle this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var heavyMethodTask = Task.Run(() => HeavyMethod());

    bool @return = false;

    using (AnotherForm anotherForm = new AnotherForm())
    {
        anotherForm.Main = this;
        anotherForm.ShowDialog();
        @return = anotherForm.Return;
    }

    await heavyMethodTask;

    if (@return)
    {
        A();
    }
    else
    {
        B();
    }
}
```

Just remember that you cannot create, access, or update UI elements from any thread other than the UI thread. So run your `HeavyMethod()` in a task instead.

---

Here's the updated version of my above answer:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    async Task<Process> StartProcessAsync(string exeFullPath, TimeSpan delay, string param = "")
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(exeFullPath))
            {
                var process =
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)
                        ? Process.Start(exeFullPath)
                        : Process.Start(exeFullPath, param);
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                return process;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }

    var processTask = (Task<Process>)null;
    if (startOutlookCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        processTask = StartProcessAsync(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0), "");
    }
    else if (startTeamsCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        processTask = StartProcessAsync(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000.0), "--processStart \"Teams.exe");
    }

    bool rtn = false;
    using (AnotherForm anotherForm = new AnotherForm())
    {
        anotherForm.Main = this;
        anotherForm.ShowDialog();
        // receive the return value from anotherForm
        rtn = anotherForm.Return;
    }

    var process = await processTask;

    if (rtn)
    {
        A();
    }
    else
    {
        B();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry. I didn't tell you that, but HeavyMethod also access UI elements.

Comment: @okaken - That's why I asked for a [mcve]. Can you please post the full and real code?

Comment: @okaken - If `HeavyMethod()` is actually heavy then it will cause your UI to freeze up while processing. You need to separate out the UI and the processing. When you post the full method I can show you what I mean.

Comment: I have added the code in the question text.
I believe you will solve this problem. You told me to check my code again. I have access to the UI, but there seems to be a way to avoid it.
However, I want to set a certain waiting time for the application startup process.
Each application launch process takes about the same amount of time as the web browser control process.

Comment: @okaken - Your code still doesn't compile and isn't complete, but I've made an answer. A full [mcve] would be appreciated.

Comment: thank you! I don't have time to test it today, but I'm sure it will probably work as I want it to. Words cannot express my gratitude.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to only change this code.

```
bool taskResult = sampleTask.reslt;
```

to

```
bool taskResult = await sampleTask;
```

Comment: The issue is the `this.BeginInvoke(act1);` line.

Comment: @Rodolfo 
I tried that but it didn't work.
I saw this answer to call another form asynchronously. It works as I expected, but if I can call the form in another way, I would like to know how to do it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323069/how-to-invoke-a-form-inside-another-form-task